# Null or weird response on S3Client when listing objects

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When I try to fetch objects from a public s3 bucket I get null or a weird response, which is an empty Object(Generator) when I var_dump it.

```
$s3 =  new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest'
]);

$result0 = $s3->listObjects([
    'Bucket' => 'pub-bucket-name'
]);

$result1 = $s3->getIterator(
    'ListObjects', 
    ['Bucket' => 'pub-bucket-name']
);

$result2 = $s3->getObject([
    'Bucket' => 'pub-bucket-name',
    'Key' => 'a_known_filename.json'
]);
```

result 0 and 2 are null, result 1 is an empty Generator Object.

Someone knows why this is happening?
I am sure about the bucket name and that it's public as I can connect via 3Hub, that's also why I know the filenames.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a public bucket, try setting 'credentials' to false:

```
$s3 =  new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => false
]);
```

That should work